# RethinkDB server on BBB crashing on basic r.db_list() command (2.1.1)

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, beagleboneblack, rethinkdb

I have version 2.1.1 RethinkDB server installed on the beaglebone black as well as the python driver.
When instantiated the server starts and I get

```
... notice: Server ready, "arm_bx9" blahhh
```

So the server is running and I get a good connection from the python client:

```
>>> import rethinkdb as rdb
>>> conn = rdb.connect()
```

At this point all is well... I am connected on localhost. The following is the line that fails every time!

```
>>> rdb.db_list().run(conn)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/ast.py", line 118, in run
    return c._start(self, **global_optargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 580, in _start
    return self._instance.run_query(q, global_optargs.get('noreply', False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 443, in run_query
    res = self._read_response(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 467, in _read_response
    = self._socket.recvall(12, deadline)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 368, in recvall
    raise ReqlDriverError("Connection is closed.")
rethinkdb.errors.ReqlDriverError: Connection is closed.
```

The corresponding log from the rethink server:

```
notice: Server ready, "arm_bx9" 68...blah
error: Error in src/arch/runtime/thread_pool.cc at line 354:
error: Segmentation fault from reading the address (nil).
error: Backtrace:
```

I can run this command against a rethinkdb server running on a  raspberry Pi without error.

The symptoms are identical to [this](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4591), even though the stimulus is different. Is there a possible thing I could have done during the make process to cause this problem?

Comment: This might be related to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rethinkdb/vAyJjaR8jnA
I just asked the other user if they could figure out a work-around.

Comment: @DanielMewes From their log file its just about exactly the same symptom...  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.0.1 runs without the error and I suspect that any 2.0.x version will exibit the same...

Thanks for all the help on this issue.

Cheers